# How to build cartesian representations of spherical Gaussian basis functions?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, basis-sets, algorithms

I'm trying to code an integral library for my own QC software from scratch. I need to use the spherical basis functions like in any other popular program. So, a D basis function is supposed to make five MOs, an F function is supposed to make seven, and so on.

But how do I find the representations for each D and higher AM basis function? Is there a general formula that can be conveniently applied to generate as many representations as necessary for angular momenta up to…  I?

$$x^iy^jz^k\exp\left(-\alpha r^2\right) \quad \text{with} \quad i + j + k = n$$

Suppose, the total angular momentum is $2,$ the number of representations thus will be $2n + 1 = 5,$ thus it is five primitive basis functions with the same centers and same exponent values, but what exactly are these representations?

Comment: See "Transformation between Cartesian and pure spherical harmonic Gaussians
H. Bernhard Schlegel, Michael J. Frisch" https://doi.org/10.1002/qua.560540202 It is also covered in good books, e.g. "Molecular Electronic Structure" Helgaker et al.

Comment: This question has popped up several times on this forum, see also https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8343/transforming-basis-functions-from-cartesian-to-speherical/8345#8345 https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4453/how-can-i-implement-the-cartesian-harmonics/4470#4470

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following Helgaker *et al.* in "[Molecular Electronic-Structure Theory](https://www.wiley.com/en-gb/Molecular+Electronic+Structure+Theory-p-9780471967552)" a real valued spherical harmonic GTO can be written as

$$\chi_{\alpha_{nl}lm}^{GTO}=N_{\alpha_{nl}lm}^{GTO}S_{lm}e^{-\alpha_{nl}r^2}$$

Where $N_{\alpha_{nl}lm}^{GTO}$ is a normalisation constant, and $S_{lm}$ is a real solid harmonic, which is the polynomial you want. The real solid harmonics obey the recurrence relations

$$S_{00}=1$$
$$S_{l+1,l+1}=\sqrt{2^{\delta_{l0}}{{2l+1}\over{2l+2}}}[xS_{l,l}-(1-\delta_{l0})yS_{l,-l}]$$
$$S_{l+1,-l-1}=\sqrt{2^{\delta_{l0}}{{2l+1}\over{2l+2}}}[yS_{l,l}+(1-\delta_{l0})xS_{l,-l}]$$
$$S_{l+1,m}={{(2l+1)zS_{lm}-\sqrt{(l+m)(l-m)}{r^2}S_{l-1,m}}\over{\sqrt{(l+m+1)(l-m+1)}}} $$

This is sufficient to evaluate the (form of the) polynomials.

Alternatively explicit formulae for the coefficients in the polynomials have been published in [Schlegel, H.B. and Frisch, M.J. (1995), Transformation between Cartesian and pure spherical harmonic Gaussians. Int. J. Quantum Chem., 54: 83-87](https://doi.org/10.1002/qua.560540202) . Again from Helgaker *et al.* these are given as follows: If $G_{lm}({\bf r},a,{\bf A})$ represents a spherical-harmonic GTO with exponent $a$ and centered at ${\bf R_A}$, and $G_{x,y,z}({\bf r},a,{\bf A})$ similarly for a Cartesian GTO then

$$G_{lm}({\bf r},a,{\bf A})=N^{S}_{lm}
\sum_{t=0}^{[(l-\left|m\right|)/2]}
\sum_{u=0}^{t}
\sum_{v=v_m}^{[\left|m\right|/2-v_m]+v_m}
C_{tuv}^{lm}G_{2t+\left|m\right|-2(u+v),2(u+v),l-2t-\left|m\right|}({\bf r},a,{\bf A})
$$

where

$$N^{S}_{lm}={1\over{2^{\left|m\right|}l!}}\sqrt{{2(l+\left|m\right|)!(l-\left|m\right|)!}\over{2^{}\delta_{0m}}}$$
$$C_{tuv}^{lm}=(-1)^{t+v-v_m}{1\over 4}^t
\binom{l}{t}
\binom{l-t}{\left|m\right|+t}
\binom{t}{u}
\binom{\left|m\right|}{2v}
$$

and

$$ v_m = 0 \space for \space m \ge 0, {1\over 2} \space for \space m<0$$

I strongly suggest you check the above formulae from the original sources for typos!